# Configuration of custom redirection with 301 status code in serverles.yml file

Tags: redirect, next.js, aws-serverless

My problem is related to specific status code of permanent redirection in next.js. Status code that I want to achieve is 301, instead of default 308 which serverless provides.

After a lot of articles, I have found out that serverless has limitation in free version, and it isn't possible to use `has` property, which could eventualy allow me to configure serverles.yml file to redirect with 301 status code.

I am aware of similiraties with 301 and 308 status code, both of them will provide a permanent redirect, but in my case, I would like to customize redirection with 301 status code.

Is it possible to achive that? If someone has similar issue, please share with me. Thank you in advance!

[description from serverless official docs about redirection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtLQ2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can send a response with this header:

```js
return res.writeHeade(301, 'Location': '/targert-url'}
```

====> [also check this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/creating-a-serverless-redirect-function-600816603d48)